# MySQL Query Optimization for GPS Tracking system

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `alltrackers`
WHERE `deviceid`='FT_99000083401624'
AND `locprovider`!='none'
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

This is the show create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `alltrackers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `deviceid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `gpsdatetime` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `locprovider` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `statename` (`statename`),
  KEY `gpsdatetime` (`gpsdatetime`),
  KEY `locprovider` (`locprovider`), 
  KEY `deviceid` (`deviceid`(18))
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8665045 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I've removed the columns which I thought were unnecessary for this question.

This is the EXPLAIN output for this query:

> id    select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows  Extra
>
> 1 SIMPLE  alltrackers ref locprovider,deviceid    deviceid    56  const   156416  Using
> where; Using filesort

This particular query is showing as taking several seconds in mytop (mtop). I'm a bit confused though, as the same query but with a different "deviceid" doesn't take as long. Although I only need the last row, I've already removed LIMIT 1 as that makes it take even longer. This table currently contains 3 million rows.

It is used for storing the locations from different GPS devices. Each GPS device has a unique device ID. Locations come in and are added to the table. For statistics I'm running the above query to find the time of the last received location from a certain device.

I'm open to advice on ways to further optimize the query or even the tables.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need 'select *'? And what about adding a key for 'deviceid' and 'locprovider' together?

Comment: I don't need select *, I can narrow that down a bit, I thought perhaps * would be faster. Locprovider has only 4 possible values "GPS", "Cell", "None" and "". I find the query is slow even when I remove the AND locprovider!='none' bit....

Comment: How many rows does the query return?

Comment: You need to add clustered index: ALTER TABLE `alltrackers` ADD INDEX `deviceid_1` (`deviceid`, `locprovider`);

Comment: I added the deviceid,locprovider index. It is now returning this for explain:

SIMPLE alltrackers ref locprovider,deviceid,deviceid_locprovider deviceid 56 const 139351 Using where; Using filesort

this is basically the same. Should I force it to use a query? I think the reason is actually the huge size of this table. Is there a way to rethink this system, as this table will just keep growing and growing. And I do need to keep all of it for historical searching purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the last row, add an index on `(deviceid, id, locprovider)`. It would be even faster with an index on `(deviceid, id, locprovider, gpsdatetime)`:

```
ALTER TABLE alltrackers
  ADD INDEX special_covering_IDX
    (deviceid, id, locprovider, gpsdatetime) ;
```

Then try this out:

```
SELECT  id, locprovider, gpsdatetime 
FROM alltrackers
WHERE deviceid = 'FT_99000083401624'
AND locprovider <> 'none'
ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 1 ;
```

Comment: Is there any difference between '<>' and '!='?

Comment: @Roman: No, they are equivalent in MySQL (and SQL-Server). But `<>` is standard SQL and `!=` will not work in other DBMSs.

Comment: This seems to work! Can you tell me why an index on those four columns solved the problem? Many thanks!

Comment: Can you post the explain plan now (that you have created this index)?